# Combining integer and float parts of a number in C++

Tags: c++11, floating-point, fixed, floating, fractions

I have three variables

uint_8  a = The integer value lets say 11111100,
uint_4  b = The fractional part of a.  lets say .1001,
float   c

where a is 8 bits and b is 4 bits.

Is there anyway that I combine a and b in c so that c has value 11111100.1001

I need the functions that can do it. A function that separates integer and fraction is possible. But the one that I is something that I am not finding at the moment.

Comment: `c = a + b/16.f`?

Comment: Or (possibly) more efficient (depending how `a`, and `b` were stored): `c = (16*a + b)/16.f;`. You may even consider doing some bit-twiddling magic (assuming you know the binary floating point representation of your target machine).

Comment: Note that it might be worth searching for "fixed point" maths.  It's common to store `a` and `b` packed into a single integer field, which would mean that @chtz suggestion to convert to a `float` would reduce to a simple `packed / 16.f`.

Comment: So for example, we have a decimal value 3.15. The binary equivalent of this that I get is 00000011.0010. Here, 11 I get as 8 bits and .0010 I get as another 4 bits. But I want to process this as 00000011.0010 and want to store that into one float. Any insights? @SamMason

Comment: @chtz look at my comment above please

Comment: `3+2/16.f` will give you a `float` which represents binary `11.0010` (which is `3.125` in decimal, not `3.15`). I don't think I understand your last comment (at least I see nothing new to the original question in it).